# JPA hibernate retornando objetos Duplicados

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, spring-jpa

Boa noite,
estou com um problema na minha classe Service, pois ela esta retornando um objeto com valores duplicados. Mas isso somente acontece para esse método e não acontece quando estou no modo debug.

Tenho uma classe Contract e ela possui uma lista de itens. E essa classe também possui um método para adicionar um item a lista e aproveita o método do item para já colocar a instância do contrato no item:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="contracts")
public class Contract implements Serializable {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "contract",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<ItemContract> itens = new ArrayList<ItemContract>();

public void addNewItem(ItemContract itemContract) {

        itemContract.setContract(this);
        this.itens.add(itemContract);
}
```

A minha classe ItemContract possui referência para esse Contract:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "itens_contract")
public class ItemContract implements Serializable{

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="contract_id", nullable=false)
private Contract contract;

public void setContract(Contract contract) {
       this.contract = contract;
}
```

No meu service existe uma método para adicionar um novo contrato com itens e funciona de boa, mas existe um método para adicionar um item a um contrato já existente(addNewItemToContract) que quando retorna esse contrato o último item adicionado retorna duplicado.

```
    @Transactional
public ContractResponseDto addNewItemToContract(Long contractId, ItemContractCreateDto itemDto) {

    ItemContract item = this.itemContractMapper.toItemContract(itemDto);
    Contract contract = this.findByContractId(contractId);

    contract.addNewItem(item);

    contract = this.contractRepository.save(contract);
    return this.contractMapper.toContractResponseDto(contract);
}
```

Mas isso, somente acontece no retorno desse método, quando utilizo outro endpoint para buscar esse contrato ele vem direito sem itens duplicados. E também não acontece quando eu utilizo esse código em modo debug.

Descobri que seu eu fizer uma verificação na lista antes de adicionar o item, esse problema não acontece.

```
    public void addNewItem(ItemContract itemContract) {
       if(!itens.contains(itemContract)) {
          itemContract.setContract(this);
          this.itens.add(itemContract);
       }
    }
```

Mas estou na duvida do porque disso estar acontecendo, se eu cometi algum erro no relacionamento das entidades, alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Parece que você está usando o Cascade all no contract, eu faria assim para tentar corrigir:

```
@Transactional
public ContractResponseDto addNewItemToContract(Long contractId, ItemContractCreateDto itemDto) {
    ItemContract item = this.itemContractMapper.toItemContract(itemDto);
    Contract contract = this.findByContractId(contractId);

    contract.addNewItem(item);

    // Isso deve evitar duplicidade.
    this.itemContractRepository.save(item);
    contract = this.contractRepository.save(contract);
    return this.contractMapper.toContractResponseDto(contract);
}
```

Neste caso, você precisará injetar o repositório itemContractRepository em seu serviço para que seja possível salvar o item separadamente. Verifica se o método save do repositório itemContractRepository está dentro de uma transaction.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).